# Event sourcing - how to deal with race conditions and http delivery?

Tags: rest, concurrency, cqrs, event-sourcing

I try to understand how I could use event sourcing with a web application. As far as I know event sourcing is about storing db updates in form of events in an event storage. I guess synchronizing the state with the read database is done probably by a daemon, which reads out the latest events from the event storage and performs the changes on the read database.

I have many questions, but I think the best if we talk about an example scenario. For example I want to build a REST service, which has users. I have a constraint, that the user name should be unique. I have an event storage, and I have read db on which I set my constraint. Okay, now I send a `POST /users` request with an user name which is already stored in the db. First I store the `UserCreated` event in the event storage, and now what? I can generate a resource id with the event storage I guess, so I can send it back with a `201 created` header in an `GET /users/{id}` link. The client gets that link, clicks on it (probably automatically, or I can even send back a location header), but the read db is not in sync yet, so it will get a `404 not found` error... Okay, we can set the client, to wait for a response. I don't get it, on which channels should I send back a response, about the result of the sync? By languages with threads, like java, or by languages with event loop, like nodejs it's okay, I can add events and event handlers, but by languages with processes only, for example php, I have to build some sync daemon with huge memory leaks and find a way to build an event bus upon that. This can be done, but it will be hard and bloody. So after that I will get a correct response, like `500 internal server error`, or something like that. So finally I ended up with a corrupted event storage, with an invalid `UserCreated` event, and I cannot sync it with my read db...

How can I solve these kind of issues?

I still think it is a good approach to store everything in events and add some cache for data reading, but I really don't understand how should I implement this. I think event sourcing can be well suited to `websockets + zmq + nodejs`, or to similar systems, but not to `rest + php`... Maybe I lost the point by reading too much about cqrs and event sourcing... :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, in REST architectures, requests are made to specific resources, like `/users/123` or to categories of resources like `/users/`. When resource actions like adding, deleting, updating `/users/124` are performed, there may be clients which are interested in those event. If events are captured, interested clients can be notified in near real-time. This is called an event-based architecture.

Event-based architectures provide an efficient way to keep the state of event-producer and event-consumer clients synchronized with the system instead of the system periodically servicing complete state requests from event-consumer clients (i.e., poll-based clients). Often, both event-driven and poll-driven approaches are used to synchronize clients with the system.

Comment: after many search I found what you are talking about: http://www.slideshare.net/jeppec/agile-ddd-cqrs slide 83... :-)

Comment: actually with simple projects you can aggregate your events on client side and store a snapshot in the session instead of using a read model on server side, so this approach can be useful by using websockets, for example by a chat, or robotics, or by any problem domain which it is suited to... not just by projects where high availability needed...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/08/22/busting-some-cqrs-myths/).

> Consistency models are a business decision because it directly impacts
>   user experience. An eventually consistent model requires a different
>   user experience than an immediate one, and this is not something you
>   can just “slip in” to your users, or try to emulate. If you’re
>   attempting to emulate immediate consistency in an eventually
>   consistent model, you’re doing something wrong.

Event sourcing requires eventual consistency, while REST can be done with both eventual and immediate consistency. For example you can return a 202 accepted header to indicate eventual consistency. Usually we (at least I) think of REST as I send a POST, and I get back a 201 header with a hypermedia which points to the newly created resource, so I can add more stuff to that resource, modify it, etc... This way I keep my forms small... By eventual consistency, I have to add all of that stuff in a single form, or at least in a single request, unless I don't want to wait for the read - write synchronisation of event sourcing... I think it is a big challange to choose a consistency model for your application, and later it can conflict with the maintenance. For example you intend to add a feature with immediate consistency, but you have already chosen eventual consistency...

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using both architectures where appropriate in your application. You could manage the userId uniqueness constraint in a consistent way, then raise a UserRegistered event for every other interested party to consume.

Comment: Can you send a link about these hybrid solutions? I want to read more about this...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641393/user-auth-in-eventsourcing-applications) Q&A has more discussions about it